# GDAL/OGR convert AutoCAD DWG to shapefile

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, autocad, dwg

I'm trying to come up with a Python script to convert CAD files to shapefiles. The Open() calls don't error they just return None. I've tried with and without the 'CAD' driver specified.

```
GDAL version 3030200, Python IDLE 3.7.9

in_format = 'CAD'
in_file = 'CAD:COH.DWG'

#in_ds = ogr.Open(in_file)
in_ds = ogr.GetDriverByName(in_format).Open(in_file)

if in_ds == None:
    print ("failed to open file [%s] using [%s] format" % (in_file, in_format))
    sys.exit("failed")
```

Any ideas or how can I find out what out why this is failing?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that `Open` sometimes just returns a `NoneType` if it can't find the file. Maybe try passing in an absolute path (i.e. `"C:\Users\...COH.dwg"`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the absolute path with and without the CAD: prefix.